# How to store question numbers in a string

Tags: c#

I am working on a project in **C#** to compare correct quiz answers with a student's submitted answers. The program should display the missed question numbers in a label.

However my program is displaying every questions number (0-19) not just the incorrect numbers.

This is my code so far:

public Form1()
{InitializeComponent();}

```
string[] correctAnswers = { "B", "D", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "A" };

string[] studentAnswers = File.ReadAllLines("Response.txt");

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}
    private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}

    private void btnGrade_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string missedQuestions = "Missed Question Numbers: \n";
        for(int i = 0; i< 20; i+= 1)
        {
            missedQuestions += i.ToString() + ", ";
        }
        disMissed.Text = missedQuestions;

        int correct = 0;
        int incorrect = 0;

        if (correctAnswers[0] == studentAnswers[0])
        {
            correct += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            incorrect += 1;
            missedQuestions += "";
        }
        if (correctAnswers[1] == studentAnswers[1])
        {
            correct += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            incorrect += 1;
            missedQuestions += "";
        }
```

if/else continues for all number 0-19

```
        if (correct >= 14)
        {
            disPassFail.Text = "Pass";
        }
        else
        {
            disPassFail.Text = "Fail";
        }

        disCorrect.Text = correct.ToString();
        disIncorrect.Text = incorrect.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably becaouse you insert all the numbers from 0 to 19 to `missedQuestions` variable.

```
 for(int i = 0; i< 20; i+= 1)
 {
     missedQuestions += i.ToString() + ", ";
 }
 disMissed.Text = missedQuestions;
```

You should iterate all 20 questions and in every iteration check if the answer is correct.

```
for(int i = 0; i< 20; i+= 1)
{
    if(correctAnswers[i] == studentAnswers[i]) 
    {
       ++correct;
    }
    else
    {
        if(missedQuestions.Length > 0)
             missedQuestions += ", ";
        missedQuestions += i.ToString();
    }
}
```

And finally you can calculate amount of incorrectly answered questions by subtracting `20 - correct`.

Comment: I am trying to list each question number that the student missed (ie. 3, 7, 18, 19) not the total number of incorrect questions (ie. 4)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change code like that:

```
    string[] correctAnswers =
        {"B", "D", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "A"};

    string[] studentAnswers = File.ReadAllLines("Response.txt");

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private bool? CheckCorrect(int index)
    {
        string correctAnswer = correctAnswers[index];
        string studentAnswer = studentAnswers[index];

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(studentAnswer))
            return null;
        return correctAnswer == studentAnswer;
    }
    private void btnGrade_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> missed = new List<int>();
        List<int> correct = new List<int>();
        for (var index = 0; index < correctAnswers.Length; index++)
        {
            bool? answer = CheckCorrect(index);
            if (!answer.HasValue)
            {
                missed.Add(index);
            }

            if (answer.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                correct.Add(index);
            }
        }
        
        if (correct.Count >= 14)
        {
            disPassFail.Text = "Pass";
        }
        else
        {
            disPassFail.Text = "Fail";
        }

        string missedQuestions = "Missed Question Numbers: \n";

        missedQuestions += string.Join(",", missed.Select(x => x.ToString()));
        
        disMissed.Text = missedQuestions;

       
    }
```